# Prototype in C++

Tags: c++, prototype

Would the answer just be C and E?  I am confused as to if bool &status can be passed by reference?

You want a function that reads in data about a movie from a specified file and returns a Movie object, either via a return value or via a parameter. It should also return some indication of success or failure either via a return value or via a parameter. Which of the following would be possible prototype choices for the above requirements? Select all that apply.

```
A.  Movie readMovie(string filename);
B.  bool readMovie(string filename, Movie m);
C.  Movie readMovie(string filename, bool &status);
D.  bool readMovie(string filename, const Movie &m);
E.  bool readMovie(string filename, Movie &m);
F.  Movie readMovie(string filename, bool status);
```

Comment: Of course you can pass a `bool` by reference...

Comment: I know that but would it fit the description of the problem if you were to pass bool by status, and also it wouldnt be E because we do not want to change the movie?

Comment: all of the prototypes are *possible*, and all of them are Bad Design. in particular D is bad design. but all of them are certainly *possible*. i.e., very stupid question. incompetent questioner.

Comment: @user1853922: B and D don't allow you to get the `Movie` object populated from the file - B passes `Movie` by value (so the caller's copy remains unchanged), and D doesn't allow modifications of the passed `Movie`. C is fine, but E too.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf actually I think this is a great question. The first step to writing a correct function is understanding the interface between caller and callee. And that is the prototype.

Comment: but are you sure we want to change the movie? I do not think we want to pass Movie by reference.  But I agree one of the answers is C...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: also, they aren't all "possible" from a logical standpoint, all but two fail to implement the requested needs.

Comment: @Matteo: all of them allow the stated requirements to be fulfilled (i.e., you're wrong, you probably need to think about it, and if you don't see it after, say, half an hour, ask about the one that have you stumped). also, since none of them use exception or optional for the result, the example as a whole is **Pretty Bad Teaching**, teaching **Ungood Ways**. it's probably written by a C programmer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf how about we teach the basics before we get into SEH?

Comment: @Jonathan: you probably mean "exceptions" in the sense of C++ exceptions, not "SEH" which is a Microsoft Windows exception technology. well, exceptions are basic in C++. good C++ code is prepared for exceptions at any point, versus bad code which leaks and places the app in indeterminate state. designing C++ function prototypes without exceptions is like designing a car without wheels. it's not just nonsense: it's teaching **Ungood Ways**, ways that will hurt.

Comment: @user1853922 - Can you please explain what class this is? Namely the level and topic?

Comment: @user1853922 - Ditto on JonathonReinhart's question... (And he means "class" like "college class", not "`class Movie`" class.)......?  Is it for an introductory C++ course?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, I assume it's clear now?  Passing `status` as a `bool &` is only necessary so that the called function can write back to the caller's `status` variable.  Since `bool` is tiny (generally smaller than the size of a pointer), it would be more efficient to simply pass a bool by value, but that wouldn't allow you to write back to the caller's variable.

Answer (score 4):

All of them *can* work:

- A. if `Movie` itself can have a *well known bad value* (equivalent to `end`, `EOF` or `NULL`), or a member to check whether it's in a good state, this is fine:

  ```
  Movie readMovie(string filename);
  Movie m = readMovie(filename);
  if (m.good() || m != Movie::InvalidMovie || ... ) {
  ```

  however, I suspect the questioner *thinks* this doesn't count as *indicating success via a return value ...*
- B. if `Movie` is typedef'd to a pointer, or a `shared_ptr`, or if Movie is a lightweight wrapper for a refcounted `MovieImpl` object (for example), this is fine (because the caller's shared state is mutated via `readMovie`'s *copy* of the wrapper)

  ```
  bool readMovie(string filename, Movie m);
  ```

  however, I suspect the questioner *thinks* this doesn't count as *indicating success via a ... parameter*. (NB. A's `Movie` could also be a typedef, smart pointer or other handle-body style thing).
- C. this is definitely fine (and even the questioner knows it)

  ```
  Movie readMovie(string filename, bool &status);
  ```
- D. same constraints as B

  ```
  bool readMovie(string filename, const Movie &m);
  ```
- E. fine

  ```
  bool readMovie(string filename, Movie &m);
  ```
- F. stupid: this *can* work in the same was as A, but the status param is useless and misleading. So, I'm certain the questioner doesn't expect this to work:

  ```
  Movie readMovie(string filename, bool status);
  ```

---

So, what can really be made to work: all of them.

What the questioner probably wants to hear: C, E.

What you *should* be looking at:

- designing clear, expressive, efficient interfaces that are easy to use correctly (none of the above fit this, IMO)
- appropriate use of exceptions instead of return codes (if failure is genuinely exceptional)
- passing that `string filename` by const reference
- getting a better teacher.

Comment: That teacher is probably limited in the concepts they can include in their quiz/test questions because it's probably for an intro to C++ course where they haven't even talked about exceptions yet.  You have an argument about passing `filename` by `const &`, but that's peripheral to the question itself, which is simply trying to test the students' understanding of the meaning of various ways of passing & returning objects, given a simple set of requirements.  So I'd argue that the student shouldn't necessarily need to be looking for a better teacher.

Comment: That was a bit tongue in cheek, I really just wanted to emphasise that this exercise is artificial and should be considered poor style. It's a shame so many introductory problems seem to illustrate the basics with unnecessarily bad code.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see:

- **A** provides no boolean indication of success.  False.
- **B** is passing `Movie` by value, so there's no way it will get returned.  False.
- **C** returns a movie, and the `bool` is passed by ref so it will get modified. True.
- (skip)
- **E** is the opposite of **C**, so it will work too. True.
- (back to) **D** is the same as **E**, except it will be a `const Movie` this may or may not be appropriate.  *True?*
- **F** is the opposite of **B**, and fails for the same reason. False.

It's not a terribly clear question, and I would indicate my reasoning for my answers on the test/homework.

Comment: D can't work - he wants `Movie` to be populated by the function, and the `const` doesn't allow this.

Comment: -1 A provides success indication via the `Movie` result, hence "provides no indication of success" in the sense of "can not..." is incorrect, and in any other sense is meaningless. SImilarly for B, that's incorrect, and for F, just **incorrect** all the way.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I suppose you could return `null` to indicate failure. However, I don't think that's what the question wants. I don't know, it's not a terribly clear question. Edited.

Comment: So would the answer be B, C, and D.  I am still confused as to what is going on?  Can someone correctly sum it up and explain it?

Comment: How much more clearly can I explain it? `B` is clearly marked as False above.

Comment: Sorry Sorry didnt see it, its C and D.

Comment: It is C and E for sure. Probably also D. And if a `null` movie is a valid indicator for failure, then `A` is correct too.

Comment: A does not return a `Movie*`, it returns a full-blown `Movie` object. so it cannot be correct/True.  You can't return a NULL actual object.

Comment: The only valid choices are C and E.  No if's, ands, buts, or any further arguments, those are plain & simply, not sure how I could make myself any clearer, the only valid choices.  C and E.  Period.

Comment: Ahh, crap - too much time in C#. Yes @phonetagger you are correct. Removed the `null` mention. What about D though?

Comment: MatteoItalia is absolutely right.  Option D allows `readMovie()` to read the `Movie` object passed in, but won't allow it to change the object.  Of course this depends on `class Movie` following the rules regarding constness.  Technically the `Movie` class could have member methods declared as `const` yet they allow the object to be altered either because all of its member variables were declared `mutable` or because the `const`-declared functions cast away the constness of `this`, or the `readMovie()` function could cast away the constness of the parameter, but these are bad practices.

Comment: @phonetagger: interesting assertions, in that they're very much at odds with reality. other readers may think you're trolling. but my experience here at SO is that at SO, the more assertive someone is, the higher is the chance it's simply incompetence at work.

Comment: since it seems people here **DO NOT UNDERSTAND** how all the prototypes can be correct (and with that as starting point, can not understand how utterly incompetent the teacher is), I will write up a detailed answer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: if you **do not understand** the implied requirements of such an exercise (a "more or less POD", sensible `Movie` class, no exceptions, ...) it's not our fault; but, as you would say, there's no point in discussing this anymore, I think any regular of the C++ tag knows what's your attitude in these arguments.

Comment: You guys know what's fun? Setting egos aside for 5 minutes and just answering a question.

Comment: @Matteo: you're correct that most all regulars know my attitude: it is to be technically correct. and you're wrong, in a very incompetent-sounding way. of course you will defend that till hell freezes over. and as everybody knows, i don't freaking care about the perception that you create about me defending your wrongness, like already using ad hominem arguments about what everybody allegedly knows about me (unspecified, but implied). jeez.'

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf How about you quit sounding like an arrogant ass in comments on my answer, and get back to writing your own. Geez.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm aware that I've diagnosed you folks as incompetent since you're unwilling to admit to being wrong. That's no cause for calling me names.

Comment: I've put my opinion *and explanations* on the matter out there. You've said it's wrong. I'm still waiting on yours. My unwillingness to say I'm wrong (because I'm not yet convinced that I am) has *nothing* to do with the way you come across.

Comment: Sadly I missed the bunfight, but I suspect my answer is similar to what Alf was thinking.

Comment: @Useless: yep. although i didn't feel (after the above) that i had the luxury of just describing things. i felt it was necessary to write concrete and complete code for the most likely case.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: As suggested by MatteoItalia, I took the question at face value, inferring exactly those implied requirements that he suggests.  When the question requires `readMovie()` to return both a `Movie` object and a (presumably separate) indication of success or failure, I took it at face value that they should be returned separately.  When it said they should be returned via a return value or via a parameter, I took that at face value and didn’t look for ways to return them wrapped in something else or as a pointer (it does say to return a `Movie` object).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  Wow.  Maybe it’s best that I walked away from SO for a few hours while you unnecessarily bashed my comment.  At least my comment wasn’t made out of arrogance, though I couldn’t blame you if you or others took it that way.  I’ve continued addressing this issue in comments under your own answer.

Comment: @phonetagger: the above code is a demonstration and proof that you were **wrong** about the signatures not supporting the requirements. they do. and it's trivial. and you should have understood that earlier when it was pointed out by me. you didn't, and now you not only whine but, like Matteo Italia (whatever), introduce *fake quotes* to support the whining. me i've been corrected twice by other people since that affair. it doesn't bother me being wrong sometimes. it shouldn't bother you. stop whining, get a grip, admit to being wrong, move on.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I don't mind being wrong.  I don't mind being shown that I'm wrong.  I mind it when it's done in the context of arrogantly hinting that I'm incompetent.  You could have simply posted your own answer beginning with "Contrary to the suggestions others have made, ...", which is the approach I've taken in several of my own recent answers when earlier answerers were blatantly wrong and from comments it looked like others were clearly taken in with their wrong answers.  And, to what *fake quotes* of mine are you referring?  I carefully read through this again & can't find any.

Answer (score 1):

A movie is a **big thing**, so it should be allocated dynamically.

Therefore, use a smart pointer.

The code below demonstrates/proves how each and every proposed function signature supports returning a loaded movie and checking whether it succeeded or failed, *with the most natural interpretation of the information provided* (in particular, that a "movie" is a movie).

Note that the signatures in the question are all examples of Very Bad Design™.

The signature shown in namespace `right` in the code below is however OK:

- It supports Windows filenames in general.
- It ensures that if the load fails, the calling code has no movie object to (erroneously) play with, and this is done by throwing an exception to indicate failure.
- It passes the string by reference to `const` (for efficiency and as a general good habit).

```
#include <memory>           // std::shared_ptr
#include <new>              // std::nothrow
#include <stdexcept>        // std::runtime_error
#include <string>           // std::string

class MovieData
{
    // Whatever
};

//          *** A movie is a big thing, so it should be allocated dynamically. ***
//          *** Therefore, use a smart pointer. ***
//
typedef std::shared_ptr< MovieData > Movie;

namespace a {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    Movie readMovie(string filename)
    {
        return 0?0
            : filename == "succeed"?    Movie( ::new(nothrow) MovieData )
            : Movie();
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        Movie const m = readMovie( filepath );
        return (m != nullptr);
    }
}

namespace b {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    bool readMovie(string filename, Movie m)
    {
        if( filename != "succeed" || m == nullptr )
        {
             return false;
        }
        *m = MovieData();
        return true;
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        Movie const m( ::new(nothrow) MovieData );
        return readMovie( filepath, m );
    }
}

namespace c {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    Movie readMovie(string filename, bool &status)
    {
        status = false;
        if( filename != "succeed" )
        {
            return Movie();
        }
        Movie const result( ::new(nothrow) MovieData );
        status = true;
        return result;
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        bool result = false;
        readMovie( filepath, result );
        return result;
    }
}

namespace d {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    bool readMovie(string filename, const Movie &m)
    {
        if( filename != "succeed" || m == nullptr )
        {
            return false;
        }
        *m = MovieData();
        return true;
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        Movie const m( ::new(nothrow) MovieData );
        return readMovie( filepath, m );
    }
}

namespace e {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    bool readMovie(string filename, Movie &m)
    {
        if( filename != "succeed" )
        {
            return false;
        }
        m.reset( ::new(nothrow) MovieData );
        return (m != nullptr);
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        Movie m;
        return readMovie( filepath, m );
    }
}

namespace f {
    using std::string;
    using std::nothrow;

    Movie readMovie(string filename, bool status)
    {
        (void) status;  struct status;      // Intentionally not used.
        if( filename != "succeed" )
        {
            return Movie();
        }
        return Movie( ::new(nothrow) MovieData );
    }

    bool test( string const& filepath )
    {
        return (readMovie( filepath, bool() ) != nullptr);
    }
}

namespace right {
    using std::wstring;         // Using wide string supports nearly all Windows filenames.
    using std::runtime_error;

    Movie readMovie( wstring const& filepath )
    {
        if( filepath != L"succeed" )
        {
            throw std::runtime_error( "right::readMovie: failed because ..." );
        }
        return Movie( new MovieData );
    }

    bool test( wstring const& filepath )
    {
        try
        {
            readMovie( filepath );
            return true;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

#define TEST( name, filename ) \
    wcout << #name "::readMovie" << "( " << #filename << " ) " \
    << (name ::test( filename )? "succeeded" : "failed") << "." << endl;

#include <iostream>     // std::wcout, std::endl

int main()
{
    using std::wcout;  using std::endl;  using std::boolalpha;

    wcout << boolalpha;
    TEST( a, "succeed" );
    TEST( a, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( b, "succeed" );
    TEST( b, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( c, "succeed" );
    TEST( c, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( d, "succeed" );
    TEST( d, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( e, "succeed" );
    TEST( e, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( f, "succeed" );
    TEST( f, "fail" );
    wcout << endl;
    TEST( right, L"succeed" );
    TEST( right, L"fail" );
}
```

Output (test results):

```
a::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
a::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

b::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
b::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

c::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
c::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

d::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
d::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

e::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
e::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

f::readMovie( "succeed" ) succeeded.
f::readMovie( "fail" ) failed.

right::readMovie( L"succeed" ) succeeded.
right::readMovie( L"fail" ) failed.
```

Comment: I've read your answer and am impressed, but I like Useless's better, if only for the fact that he didn't accuse me of trolling & question my competence.  However, based on your argument, a single function signature could support passing any number of objects of any conceivable type and returning any number of objects of any conceivable type:  `void universalFunctionSignature(void* ptrToAnyStructureIncludingBothInputAndOutputParams)`.  I’m sure you could dream up a respectable number of additional signatures that could also serve as a universal function signature.

Comment: Also, contrary to your own assertion, a `Movie` object is most probably not “a big thing”, as the question says that `readMovie()` “reads in data about a movie”, not “reads & returns the entire digital content of a viewable movie.”  My guess would be that a `Movie` object would contain a few std::strings, date of release, MPAA rating, and perhaps a few other small pieces of information.  In any case, yes you are technically correct, but reasonably speaking, given the question’s premise and requirements, C and E are the most reasonable answers.

Comment: I don’t usually examine everything I come across looking for everything about it which I can criticize, but you are also correct that `filename` would be more efficiently passed in as a `const string&`, and yes, this is generally best practice.  Since you’ve helped me better myself, I figured I’d return the favor.  Passing strings as `const string&` is best practice from an efficiency standpoint, and by your admission, that’s why you mention it.  Though your test app above isn’t production code, I’m assuming it reflects your habitual coding practices. ....

Comment: ... Your `TEST()` macro is poorly constructed, and I assume reflects how you normally write `ostream` messages.  Each `operator<<` represents a separate function call, and you unnecessarily break your message string into several such calls, which adds unnecessary overhead (both computation and `.text` section space).  In addition, `std::endl` is itself a function that in this context unnecessarily flushes the ostream, again creating unnecessary overhead.  These are admittedly minor issues, but since you’re so helpful to point out everything...

Comment: ...that you think is wrong with other’s code, I figured I’d help you out with this issue.  A more efficient implementation would be as follows: `#define TEST( name, filename ) wcout << #name "::readMovie( " #filename " ) " << (name ::test( filename )? "succeeded" : "failed") << ".\n";`  ....Just thought you’d like to know.

Comment: @phonetagger: don't focus on micro-efficiency, focus on clarity first, and secondly on robustness. replacing `endl` with `\n` seldom buys you anything worthwhile, because if you're doing time-critical i/o then iostreams are most often the entirely wrong choice, efficiency-wise. even after you've turned off synchronization with C streams (tip: that has generally much greater effect than avoiding line flushes).

Comment: @phonetagger: with C++11 there one situation where taking a string argument by value is generally accepted Best Practice, namely where the string is going to be stored. in this case a string object has to be constructed anyway (it's just `move`d around), so as a practical default one can just take it by value. i didn't discuss that in the answer because it would probably constitute more "noise" to most readers than practically useful info, but i think since you're bringing up this issue it's the least i can do to mention it. as i recall herb's site has some guidelines, too. :-)

Comment: Not focused on micro-efficiency.  It's a habit thing.  If you're in the habit of using extraneous `operator<<` calls, you will do that.  If you're in the habit of using them only as necessary, you will do that.  It's like preferring prefix `operator++` over postfix `operator++` when there is otherwise no difference, due to the unnecessary construction of a temporary in the postfix case.  If you're in the habit of using prefix when it otherwise makes no difference, that's a good thing.  But I'm betting your personality can't let this one go & will have to follow up to tell me how wrong I am.

Comment: @phonetagger: i'm happy to discuss technical stuff even if SO comments are designed to be awkward for discussion. so, did point you and other readers towards some useful info about the issues you raised. but discussion about personality is just noise, sorry.

Comment: Discussion about personality?  Really?  What about discussion about competence? (ref. your first comment under Jonathon Reinhart's answer, also your comments about the competence of the "Beginner's Intro to C++" teacher who wrote the question listed in the OP's post).  I've considered the scathing remarks both you and Useless made about that poor teacher.  That teacher is probably limited in the concepts they can include in their quiz/test questions because it's for an intro to C++ course where they haven't even talked about exceptions yet.